# Unable to store UUIDs in H2 2.0.202 with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, h2, hibernate-spatial

We have been using H2 for our integration tests for quite some time. Now that H2 2.0.202 is out, we are trying to upgrade our codebase to it. We are unable to persist entities, that use java.util.UUID as a type. Consider the following example

```
public class MyEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private UUID id;
}
```

If we try to save it in an H2 database using Hibernate, this fails with a `JdbcSQLDataException` with the message `Value too long for column`. The test is as simple as

```
@DataJpaTest
class H2Test {

  @Autowired MyRepository myRepository;

  @Test
  void testSave() {
    myRepository.save(new MyEntity());
    Assertions.assertThat(myRepository.findAll()).hasSize(1);
  }
}
```

You can find the full stack trace on [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/fRpwTqLn).

We are using the org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.h2geodb.GeoDBDialect, and this seems to be one of the causes of this problem. If we remove it, the simple test case above works fine, unfortunately we are using spatial data, so we need this dialect.
I wonder if this is simply a missing compatibility between H2 2.0.202 and Hibernate? Or is there something we could do in our configuration? I could not find an issue that matches this problem in the hibernate jira, and somehow I cannot create one either.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that cause is a clash between the UUID and the Geometry types in Hibernate / Hibernate Spatial.See e.g. this issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11490

This problem should be resolved in versions 5.4.31 and later.

It can also be solved by annotating the id member variable with an explicit
`@Column(columnDefinition = "uuid")` annotation.

Comment: Oh wow, that is an old issue. I did search for Hibernate issues, but discarded everything that was older than a few months... Thank you for digging this up, I will check if this is actually the case on Monday when I am back at work.

Comment: Setting `@Column(columnDefinition = "uuid")` actually resolved an issue I was having with the embedded H2 Spring Boot Test DB not returning any Results when querying by uuid. Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this with

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType") // <-------------------------- THIS LINE
  private UUID id;
```